# SQL Function with Variable as db name within SELECT

Tags: sql, t-sql

My first problem was trying to use a return value as a variable for the database name on a JOIN.

I originally came across this website:
[Link](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/86143/how-to-join-a-table-with-a-table-valued-function)

From this I needed to create my first SQL function, and I've only been able to get somewhere with a Scalar-valued Function as I've been led to believe I need to declare variable and use the EXEC() to execute the query.

My function looks like this:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE FUNCTION getDocumentNumber(@jobNo char(8), @docID int) 
RETURNS varchar
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @dbName varchar(50)
    DECLARE @sql varchar(500)
    DECLARE @output varchar(50)

    SET @dbName = 'Job_' + @jobNo
    SET @sql = 'SELECT d.[Doc No Int] 
    FROM [' + @dbName + '].[dbo].[Documents] d 
    WHERE d.[id] = ' + @docID

    EXEC @sql = @output 
    RETURN @output
END
GO
```

My original SELECT statement now looks like this:

```html
SELECT CONCAT(ty.name, '-', co.code, ' ', FORMAT(rt.number, '000'), ' response overdue.') AS 'Description', 
    rt.[response_due_date] AS 'Date Due', 
    [dbo].getDocumentNumber(p.[Job Number], rt.[document_id]) AS 'Document No.', 
    p.[Job Number] AS 'Job No.', 
    p.[Job Title] AS 'Job Title', 
    p.[Project Manager], 
    'RFI / TQ' AS 'Type'  
FROM [Project].[dbo].[RFI_TQ] rt
JOIN [Project].[dbo].[RFI_TQ_Type] ty 
    ON rt.type_id = ty.id 
JOIN [MyCompany].[dbo].[Company] co 
    ON rt.company_id = co.id 
JOIN [Job_Register].[dbo].[Projects] p 
    ON rt.project_id = p.id 
WHERE rt.[response_due_date] < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
    AND p.[Project Manager] = 'Full Name' 
ORDER BY rt.response_due_date DESC;
```

When I try to execute I get the following error:

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'SELECT d.[Doc No Int] FROM [Job_00000001].[dbo].[Documents] d WHERE d.[id] = ' to data type int.

I've looked and searched, I think my problem is getting the returned value from the EXEC() but I can't figure out how to write the SELECT statement with variable for database name without making the SELECT statement a varchar variable.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

*Edit: apologies for the html code snippet, it would not let me post that section with Ctrl + K code indent.*

Comment: With limited exceptions, you cannot use `EXEC` inside a `FUNCTION`, as UDFs are meant to be free from side-effects. See the notes in the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-function-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: It looks like you're trying to do meta-programming (i.e. Dynamic SQL) with UDFs. That really isn't something you can do.

Comment: Aside: The best practice when assembling object names into dynamic SQL statements is to use [`QuoteName()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql) to avoid problems with odd names, e.g. `New Table` with a space or reserved words like `From`. It does more than just add a pair of square brackets.

Comment: What the error is telling you: According to the rules for [data type precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) when you add an `int` (`@docID`) to a string (`'SELECT d.[Doc No Int] ... WHERE d.[id] = '`) the string is converted to an `int`. You might want to `cast` (or `convert`) the `int` to a string if you want to concatenate string values.

Answer (score 0):

Inside function you can't use EXEC command.
Instead of using function you can try to write dynamic sql and execute it with sp_executesql.
[Please check this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), hope to help you.